# Parse error at end of "let" in Haskell file

Tags: haskell, parse-error

In this Haskell code, what error can you see at the end of "b2"? I believe there is no error, but this code in the file Q3.hs:

```
let idPnumber a1 b2= take 3 a1 == take 3 b2
```

gives the error:

```
Q3.hs:1:45: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
1 | let idPnumber a1 b2= take 3 a1 == take 3 b2 
  |                                             ^
```

Comment: Show the full error, and the full function.

Comment: The full error is here: Q3.hs:1:45: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)               The full code/ function is the one i placed above

Comment: It is missing the `in` clause I guess, but you should provide the full code sample such that we can debug it.

Comment: @HankySpanky That's definitely not the whole code, as `let` on top-level yields a parser error in Haskell 98 or 2010.

Comment: This code would work in ghci but not in a file due to small differences.  Try removing the `let`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling a Haskell source file, like `Q3.hs`, the definitions of functions at the "top level" of the program need to have a syntax that looks like this:

```
idPnumber a1 b2= take 3 a1 == take 3 b2
```

without any `let`.  Instead, `let` is used *within* functions to give a name to an expression, like this:

```
idPnumber a1 b2 = let threeA1 = take 3 a1
                      threeB2 = take 3 b2
                  in  threeA1 == threeB2
```

and -- in this case -- must be followed by an `in` clause.  (There are also some other ways that `let` can be used that don't require `in`, but those don't apply here.)

Because the `in` keyword is missing in your file, GHC has gotten hopelessly confused and has given you an error message that doesn't make much sense.  (If you added an `in` clause, you'd still get an error message, but it would explain that GHC was looking for a "top-level declaration", which is a definition like the one above without any `let` keyword.

Note that you *can* use `let` like this at the GHCi interactive prompt, but that's because the interactive prompt behaves differently than compiling a program in a file.